# Mysql Cluster stored procedure with subselect group by and order by is slow

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

i have migrated this stored procedure from ms sql server 2012 to mysql cluster.

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'%'
PROCEDURE get_activeSub(IN p_top int, IN p_carrierid int, IN p_mode int)
BEGIN

DECLARE v_tomorrow datetime;
DECLARE v_temp int;
DECLARE v_sysdate datetime;

SET v_tomorrow = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

IF (p_mode IS NULL) THEN
    SET p_mode = 0;
END IF;

IF ((p_mode != 0) AND (p_mode != 1)) THEN
    SET p_mode = 0;
END IF;

IF (p_mode = 0) THEN


SET v_sysdate = SYSDATE();
SELECT
activeSub.*
FROM 
(
SELECT
--              e.msisdn
--              ,e.hasCredit
--              ,e.lastBillingDate
-- ,
MIN(a.schedulingId) AS schedulingIdMin
FROM
activeSub a
LEFT OUTER JOIN endUser e /*force INDEX for ORDER BY (IDX_enduser_lastBillingDate)*/ ON e.endUserId = a.endUserId
INNER JOIN smartBillingInterval sb ON a.serviceId = sb.serviceId    AND sb.transactionTypeId = 7
WHERE 
(a.stateId IN (2000, 2007, 2008) OR a.stateid IS NULL)
AND a.nextBillingDate < v_tomorrow
AND a.carrierId = p_carrierId
AND (a.numRetry IS NULL OR a.numRetry <= sb.maxRetry_full)
AND (a.lastBillingPrice IS NULL OR (a.lastBillingPrice = sb.price_full AND a.nextBillingDate < v_sysdate))
GROUP BY
e.enduserid
--              ,e.hasCredit 
--              ,e.lastBillingDate
ORDER BY 
e.hasCredit DESC
,e.lastBillingDate DESC
LIMIT p_top
) aGrouped INNER JOIN activeSub ON activeSub.schedulingId = aGrouped.schedulingIdMin
ORDER BY activeSub.numRetry;


ELSE


SELECT
COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(*) AS QUANTITY
FROM activeSub a
left outer join endUser e
ON e.endUserId = a.endUserId
INNER JOIN smartBillingInterval sb
ON a.serviceId = sb.serviceId AND sb.transactionTypeId = 7
-- where stateId not in (71010,21010) and nextBillingDate<@tomorrow and a.carrierId=@carrierId
WHERE (stateId IN (2000, 2007, 2008) OR stateid IS NULL)
AND nextBillingDate < v_tomorrow
AND a.carrierId = p_carrierId
-- NUMRETRY IN INTERVALS
AND (numRetry IS NULL OR numRetry <= sb.maxRetry_full)
-- NEXT PRICE TO USE, TAKING CARE ABOUT SHORT-RETRIES FOR FULL PRICES SWEPT
AND (lastBillingPrice IS NULL OR (lastBillingPrice = sb.price_full AND nextBillingDate < SYSDATE()))
GROUP BY    e.msisdn,
e.hasCredit,
e.lastBillingDate) AS Q;
END IF;
END


    i call them with call  get_activesub(300,101101,0)

    the structure of tables involved are


    USE lisabel;
    CREATE TABLE lisabel.activesub (
        endUserId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        serviceId int(11) NOT NULL,
        carrierId int(11) NOT NULL,
        shortCodeId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        schedulingId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
        pendingDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        subscriptionDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        firstBillingDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        numBilling int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        numCredits int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        originId int(11) NOT NULL,
        text varchar(160) DEFAULT NULL,
        hierarchyId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        subscriptionHierarchyId int(11) NOT NULL,
        contentId bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        moId bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        channel varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        pinCode varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
        transactionId bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        nextBillingDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        deliveryReportId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        retCode varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        numRetry int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        numShortRetry int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        stateId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        previousStateId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        page varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        handsetId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        lastBillingDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        banningCount int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        flowId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        subscriptionNumRetry int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        subscriptionNumShortRetry int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        debit int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        partnerNotificationMask varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
        lastBillingPrice decimal(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
        sessionId bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
        gclid varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        msisdn varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (endUserId, serviceId),
        INDEX FK_activeSub_content USING BTREE (contentId),
        INDEX FK_activeSub_deliveryReport USING BTREE (deliveryReportId),
        INDEX FK_activeSub_handset USING BTREE (handsetId),enter code here
        INDEX FK_activeSub_hierachy USING BTREE (hierarchyId),
        INDEX FK_activeSub_origin USING BTREE (originId),
        INDEX FK_activeSub_shortCode USING BTREE (shortCodeId),
        INDEX FK_activeSub_subscriptionHierarchy USING BTREE (subscriptionHierarchyId),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_carrierId USING BTREE (carrierId),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_endUserId USING BTREE (endUserId),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_lastBillingPrice USING BTREE (lastBillingPrice),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_nextBillingDate USING BTREE (nextBillingDate),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_numRetry USING BTREE (numRetry),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_schedulingId USING BTREE (schedulingId),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_serviceId USING BTREE (serviceId),
        INDEX IDX_activesub_stateId USING BTREE (stateId)
    )
    ENGINE = NDBCLUSTER
    AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 204
    CHARACTER SET latin1
    COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;


    USE lisabel;
    CREATE TABLE lisabel.enduser (
        endUserId bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        msisdn varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        carrierId int(11) NOT NULL,
        handsetId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        hasCredit bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
        lastBillingDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        lastAttemptDate datetime DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (endUserId),
        INDEX FK_endUser_handset USING BTREE (handsetId),
        INDEX FK_endUsers_carrier USING BTREE (carrierId),
        INDEX IDX_enduser_endUserId USING BTREE (endUserId),
        INDEX IDX_enduser_lastBillingDate USING BTREE (lastBillingDate),
        UNIQUE INDEX IDX_enduser_msisdn USING BTREE (msisdn)
    )
    ENGINE = NDBCLUSTER
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 2040353
    AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 60
    CHARACTER SET latin1
    COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

both tables are table in memory.
table activesub have 300.000 records the enduser table have 2.000.000 records.
if i run explain extended

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT
activeSub.*
FROM 
(`enter code here`
SELECT
--              e.msisdn
--              ,e.hasCredit
--              ,e.lastBillingDate
-- ,
MIN(a.schedulingId) AS schedulingIdMin
FROM
activeSub a
LEFT OUTER JOIN endUser e USE INDEX for ORDER BY (IDX_enduser_lastBillingDate) ON e.endUserId = a.endUserId
INNER JOIN smartBillingInterval sb ON a.serviceId = sb.serviceId    AND sb.transactionTypeId = 7
WHERE 
(a.stateId IN (2000, 2007, 2008) OR a.stateid IS NULL)
AND a.nextBillingDate < '2014-12-15'
AND a.carrierId = 101101
AND (a.numRetry IS NULL OR a.numRetry <= sb.maxRetry_full)
AND (a.lastBillingPrice IS NULL OR (a.lastBillingPrice = sb.price_full AND a.nextBillingDate < sysdate()))
GROUP BY
e.enduserid
--              ,e.hasCredit 
--              ,e.lastBillingDate
ORDER BY 
e.hasCredit DESC
,e.lastBillingDate DESC
LIMIT 300
) aGrouped INNER JOIN activeSub ON activeSub.schedulingId = aGrouped.schedulingIdMin
ORDER BY activeSub.numRetry;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

The result is:

```
    1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  300 100 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
    1   PRIMARY activeSub   ref IDX_activesub_schedulingId  IDX_activesub_schedulingId  8   aGrouped.schedulingIdMin    1   100 (null)
    2   DERIVED a   ref IDX_activesub_stateId,IDX_activesub_lastBillingPrice,IDX_activesub_numRetry,IDX_activesub_nextBillingDate,IDX_activesub_carrierId,IDX_activesub_serviceId   IDX_activesub_carrierId 4   const   305303  100 Parent of 3 pushed join@1; Using where with pushed condition (((`lisabel`.`a`.`stateId` in (2000,2007,2008)) or isnull(`lisabel`.`a`.`stateId`)) and (`lisabel`.`a`.`nextBillingDate` < '2014-12-15')); Using temporary; Using filesort
    2   DERIVED sb  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   lisabel.a.serviceId,const   1   100 Child of 'a' in pushed join@1; Using where
    2   DERIVED e   eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_enduser_endUserId   PRIMARY 8   lisabel.a.endUserId 1   100 Child of 'a' in pushed join@1; Using where
```

And the workbench execution plan is:

[image]

**The execution time is 2.5 - 3 seconds. How you can improve the execution time?**

Comment: Uh ... MySQL Cluster isn't good at complex queries, and MySQL in general isn't good at optimizing subselects ... which exact MySQL Cluster version are you using?

Comment: so oracle linux 6.5 mysql cluster 5.6.19-ndb-7.3.6-cluster-commercial-advanced

Comment: in that case you should make use of your commercial support contract with Oracle?

Comment: surely we will, first I wanted to know if anyone has fought against this problem...many thanks...stay tuned..:)

Comment: just to info...i've sent request at oracle support